# Do the VBM and CBM have to be on the high symmetry point?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, k-points, solid-state-physics

I am trying to generate the band structure of a slab, a lot of tutorials tell me that I need to generate the high symmetry K point path, but I am wondering that if the VBM and CBM have to be on the high symmetry point?

Comment: Does VBM = valence band maximum and CBM = conduction band minimum here? If so, it might be a duplicate of https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6647/671

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate @anyon. As a brief note: no, they don't have to be on high-symmetry points or paths, although they are for many materials. This is because bands along a high-symmetry path have to be local maxima or minima (by symmetry!).

Comment: @PhilHasnip, A lot of papers don’t explain why they choose their k-path, is there any material of which the vbm and cbm are not on the high symmetry point?

Comment: @Jack it looks like this question might get closed. Have you read all the answers in the suggested duplicate question? If there's something in those answers that you don't understand, do you think you can ask your follow-up questions as comments to those answers?

Comment: @Jack Silicon springs to mind - the CBM is near the X-point, but not on it. It is on a high-symmetry path, though.